# Creating a viewing registry using UML

Tags: uml

I would like to create a registry of the times a user has viewed audio visual content.  I created the following diagram and was wondering if it would be a good way to achieve it.
Note: *The AudiovisualContent is connected to DateTimeStamp just as a way to record when it was added to the platform.*

[image: UML class diagram]

Comment: You allow only a single time stamp for viewing. Seems a bit restricing for a registry, doesn't it? Also note that SO is no place for reviews. Please stick to a more specific question.

Comment: @qwerty_so In fact a user ("profile") can view a content multiple times, but each viewing has only one time stamp. And if I understood correctly,  the user can give a different rating at each view.

Comment: @Christophe Well, yes. But making DateTimeStamp an instnace is pointless this way.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about not putting in a specific question.  I guess my main issues were with the multiplicities as they're always a bit confusing.  But the provided answer below was really well made and explained everything perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is the diagram correct and is it meaningful?

The diagram seems formally correct and has the advantage of being very clear on multiplicity and role names for the `DateTimeStamp`.

It is diffucult to say if this approach is correct for a "registry". But it makes sense at first sight; I understand from the diagram that:

- a `Profile` (user?) can do several `Viewing` and each `Viewing` is about one `Audiovisual Content`.  Conversely, an `Audiovisual Content` can be the subject of several `Viewing`, and each `Viewing` is performed by a `Profile`
- Each `Viewing` (of a given content by a given user) has a `DateTimeStamp`
- Each `Audiovisual Content` has a `DateTimeStamp` corresponding to the moment the content was added.
- If a user views the same content several time at different moments,  each of this Viewing may have a different rating, and the rating is optional.

What I can further infer from the multiplicities, is that the timestamp corresponds to the beginning of the viewing act (because if it would be the end of the viewing, there wouldn't be timestamp when the viewing starts, so the multiplicity would have been 0..1).

### Areas of concern

The `DateTimeStamp` is a class according to your diagram.  The fact that you have a `1` multiplicity on the side of the `Viewing` and on the side of `Audiovisual Content` means that every single timestamp must be associated with BOTH.  I doubt that this is correct.

You could consider using `0..1` instead, which would leave the possibility of having a time stamp associated with only one of the two or none at all.  But still the timestamp could possibly have both, with the risk of inconsistency between them.

Personanlly, I'd go for `*` to clarify that many viewing and uploading could happen at the same time.  I'd probably show it as a property `-addedOn: DateTimeStamp` and `-viewedOn:DateTimeStamp`.

In reality, the time stamp is very probably a value object.  You could then consider making it a `«dataType»`; showing it as a property may then seem even more intuitive.

***Unrelated:** while your current way of modeling `Viewing` as a class is perfectly fine, you may be interested to show is as an association class between many `Profile` and many `Audiovisual Content`*

Comment: Thanks, that was an amazing answer! :D